# unable to use objectAtIndex property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

im trying to load a set of images from web and display it on the screen  within a collection view. Following is my code

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                  @"http://elatewiki.org/images/thumb/Google.png/120px-Google.png"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    //recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipePhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:recipPhotoUrl[0] ]];
    return cell;
}
```

but i have to use the `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` property along with imageWithData so the image can be swiped . Is there any ways through which i can use objectAtIndex:indexPath.row along with `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL` ?

Comment: Where are defined `recipePhotos` and `recipPhotosUrl`?

Comment: recipePhotos contains the name of static image files

Comment: recipePhotoUrl contains all the urls from where the photos can be fetched dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use this:**

```
 NSString *url_str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[recipPhotoUrl objectAtIndex: indexPath.item]];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:url_str];
 recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the for?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
              @"http://elatewiki.org/images/thumb/Google.png/120px-Google.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

Anyway, you were close to solution....

```
if (recipPhotoUrl.count > indexPath.row)
{
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:recipPhotoUrl[indexPath.row]]];
}
```

But still, you are doing this operations on the `main thread` and you, for sure, block the UI, the scroll will not be smooth.
It also not so sure as you're accessing the index without checking if the array has a sufficient dimension.

Comment: the app crashes when i do so. how to run this on worker thread?

Comment: the app still crashes when i use dispatchqueue

Comment: Are you checking if the array has the right dimension?

Comment: no im trying to get the index of the row and fix the image using objectAtIndex property...

Answer (score -2):

`UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];`
should be placed in a common function.For example -(void)viewDidLoad, add a property reference to image .

`recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:recipPhotoUrl[0]]];`

change to

`recipeImageView.image = self.image;`

Comment: That's not so helpful. He is asking how to fetch the images from dynamic url from the array. And this is on the main thread...